# Simple PIN validation

Tags: javascript

Task:
ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.
If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return false.

My solution:

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
  if (!isNaN(pin) && Number.isInteger(pin) && pin.toString().length == 4 || pin.toString().length == 6) { 
    return true 
  } else { 
    return false 
  }
}
```

The only bug I get is when I pass 4 digits as a string (`"1234"`) - it equals `false`.

Comment: Add this as the first line of the function: `pin = Number(pin);`

Comment: Well, not the only bug – it also returns true for strings like "1234ab".

Comment: `!isNaN(pin)` --- this check makes no sense.

Comment: Regex in this case would really be the easiest way to handle it -`/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin)`.

Comment: Please review my answer, it should work as asked!

Comment: `validatePIN=/./.test.bind(/^\d{4}|\d{6}$/)`

Comment: @zerkms, thx! It works. But I haven't experience with RegExp, so I don't understand how it works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
function validatePIN (pin) {
  return typeof pin === 'string' && // verify that the pin is a string
    Number.isInteger(+pin) && // make sure that the string is an integer when converted into a number
    [4, 6].includes(pin.length) // only accepts 4 and 6 character pins
}
```

Comment: @b00t, try `0000` or `000000` - it equals `false`

Comment: If `typeof pin === "string"`, then surely `!isNaN(Number(pin)` -- the `NaN` check is superflous

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus, removing the isNaN will break it. The function wouldn't return correctly for '0000'.

Comment: @b00t `isNaN` check there makes no sense at all.

Comment: @zerkms, there are other options as well, but simply having `Number(pin)` would evaluate '0000' to 0, which would evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @b00t that's right, but `isNaN` is the wrong tool for the job. Just check: `isNaN(Number('Infinity'))`

Comment: @zerkms, well in this specific use case it isn't, as 'Infinity'.length doesn't equal to 4 or 6? But you are correct, in a more dynamic situation it isn't perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
var isNumber = /^\d+$/.test(pin) && (pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6)
return isNumber
}

validatePIN('0193')

//returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.every()`, `Array.prototype.some()`, `String.prototype.match()`

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>validate pin</button>
<script>
  var validatePIN = (args) => {[...args] = args;
 return args.every(v => v.match(/\d/)) &&
    [4, 6].some(n => args.length === n)};

  document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("click", (e) =>
    alert(validatePIN(e.target.previousElementSibling.value))
  )
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using `.match()` why wouldn't you validate the whole PIN with a single regex? (Also, doesn't `.match()` return null if there is no match, thus resulting in an error when you try to check the length?)

Comment: @nnnnnn You are correct. Just an optional approach. `RegExp` by zerkms should return expected result.

Comment: Well it is an interesting way of looking at it.

Comment: `validatePIN('a') // exception`. Also `(pin = String(pin))` --- this makes very little sense.

Comment: @zerkms See updated post. Was initially considering either `Number` or `String` input for function, missed that `.value` is string

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean?

Comment: `validatePIN('abcd')` --- this is what I mean. Default value there makes no sense.

Comment: @zerkms _"`validatePIN('abcd')` --- this is what I mean. Default value there makes no sense."_ Still not following what you mean?

Comment: `validatePIN('abcd')` - what does this return for you? What should it return?

Comment: @zerkms `validatePIN("abcd")` returns `false`, here. If interpret Question correctly, result should be `false`

Comment: Please don't treat people as idiots here: you have changed your answer after my comment.

Comment: `validatePIN('1234')` --- now this is `false`, while it should be `true`. Here is a #protip for you: check your code before you randomly change it next time. The default value still makes no sense.

Comment: @zerkms See updated post. _"Here is a #protip for you: check your code before you randomly change it next time."_ Ok. Have you not edited some of you Answers at SO?

Comment: I have, but I do not pretend it was like that before. `([...args] = args)` --- this still makes no sense. Why do you put a default value there? `validatePIN()` --- call it without parameters and see that your default value causes an exception.

Comment: @zerkms _"I have, but I do not pretend it was like that before."_ Surely you are  mistaken. Do not "pretend" anything, here. Updated post several occasions during this  communication, in direct response to communication. This is what is supposed to occur, yes? that is, improve possible solution. Not certain how any portion of this exchange was interpreted as "pretend", there? Ok, believe getting it about default value and calling without parameters, will try to improve

Comment: `var validatePIN = args => [4, 6].some(n => args.length === n) && [...args].every(v => v.match(/\d/));` --- but boy it's ugly

Comment: @zerkms `var validatePIN = args => !!args && (len = args.length) && [4,6].some(n => n === (args.split(/\D/)[0].length === len))`

Comment: @guest271314 global variables - disgusting. Why do you people prefer some terrible code when you can have a concise and readable one `const validatePIN = pin => /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin)`

Comment: @zerkms Yes, agreed. Actually prefer your approach at solution. Attempting to determine if possible for any iterable or other approaches to match the conciseness of your example

Comment: Well, `pin` is always a string `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
  return /^\d+$/.test(pin) && (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
    if (pin.length !== 4 && pin.length !== 6) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < pin.length; i++) {
    if (pin[i] > '9' || pin[i] < '0') {
       return false;
    }

  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Glad to have you apart of the community!
Please be sure to checkout our help section 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to solve using regular expression.

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
  return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin)
}

validatePIN('2345')
//returns true

validatePIN('2.45')
//reutrns false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
  if (pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6) 
    {
      for (let i = 0; i < pin.length; i++)
        {
          if (pin[i] == "0" ||
              pin[i] == "1" ||
              pin[i] == "2" ||
              pin[i] == "3" ||
              pin[i] == "4" ||
              pin[i] == "5" ||
              pin[i] == "6" ||
              pin[i] == "7" ||
              pin[i] == "8" ||
              pin[i] == "9") ;
          else return false;
        }
      return true;
    }
  else return false;
}
```

this code checks the PIN-length and passes all test tasks with numbers and not numbers...

Comment: It's useful to describe what your code does, so people can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean validatePin(String pin) {
  return pin.matches("\\d{4}|\\d{6}");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.