# stuck on codewar challenge, not passing everytime

Tags: javascript

ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.

If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return false.

eg:

validatePIN("1234") === true

validatePIN("12345") === false

validatePIN("a234") === false

MY CODE:

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
  //return true or false
  if (typeof(pin)==="number"){
    if (pin.toString().length===4 || pin.toString().length===6){
    return true;
    } 
  } else {
  return false;
  }
}
```

When I click on the 'attempt' button, it comes back with some failed attempts.

Passed: 21 Failed: 37 Errors: 1

Wrong output for '1234' - Expected: true, instead got: false

Wrong output for '0000' - Expected: true, instead got: false

Wrong output for '1111' - Expected: true, instead got: false

Wrong output for '123456' - Expected: true, instead got: false

Wrong output for '098765' - Expected: true, instead got: false

Wrong output for '000000' - Expected: true, instead got: false

Wrong output for '123456' - Expected: true, instead got: false

Wrong output for '090909' - Expected: true, instead got: false

Comment: What is the error? Which test cases fail? What is your question?

Comment: `validatePIN("1234")` fails becuase typeof would be `string`, you probably don't want to use that to validate that the input is numeric. Also `validatePIN(NaN)` is probably your error, as it returned `undefined`

Comment: `typeof('1234') !== "number"`

Comment: Read the problem description carefully: *"If the function is passed a valid PIN **string**, return true, else return false."*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168266/simple-pin-validation

duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You're probably failing every single one that might return true, because your input is not a number. Yes, digits exist, but they are in the form of a string, AKA text. You need to do some form of checking. An implementation would be to filter out anything that's not a number using regex and compare it to the string that was inputted. [Here](https://regexr.com/) is a good website to play around with regex after you're more versed in it.

```
let pin = '1432a'
let filteredString = pin.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") //"1432"
pin === filteredString //false

pin = '142'
filteredString = pin.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") //"142"
pin === filteredString //true
```

Comment: `parseInt` is not the right function to use. `parseInt('123foo')` returns `123`.